# View source function for onChange field event in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, xrm

The onChange event for a field on my opportunity form is being called twice and I'm trying to track down the source of the second call. I've already passed the execution context into the onChange function but don't know any way to see the source of the call from there. Now I'm wondering if there's a way to see the pending events for an XRM page, does anyone know where that information is?

My code is basically this, tied to `onLoad` of the opportunity form. There could be a plugin or 3rd party library or something updating the field, but nothing jumps out.

```
function onLoad() {
    Xrm.Page.data.process.addOnStageChange(handleStageChange);
}

function handleStageChange() {
    var dateFieldName = "new_enteredstage1"
    var dateFieldAttr = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(dateFieldName);
    if (dateFieldAttr) {
        dateFieldAttr.setValue(new Date());
    }
}
```

If new_enteredstage1 is null when the stage change occurs then 2 calls occur and the value is set and immediately reset to null. If new_enteredstage1 has a value the value is updated as expected. Again, there could be some third party code that I'm missing but I have no idea how to track it down.

UPDATE:

This only happens on date fields, and it happens on all date fields. If I replace the code with a number field the value is not reset to null.

Comment: Never experienced this, which version of CRM is it and can you include the event handler in the question ?

Comment: Updated the question to add my code. Microsoft Dynamics 365
Version 1612 (8.2.1.207) (DB 8.2.1.207) online

Comment: I'd start from duplicating the function (i.e. make handleStageChange, handleStageSelected) so you add two distinct handlers, might help in tracking down what's happening

Comment: Commented out the addOnStageSelected bit and it's still happening, removed it from the question.

Comment: Put a debugger, try to F10 / F11 till the end of scripts from beginning of form load. This way you can see all the scripts loaded, used & called. May be you ll find a breakthrough.

Answer (score 0):

There's a know issue ([example](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/165954)) related to the "new" form rendering engine (Turbo Forms) that can cause this issue.

You can try using the legacy form rendering engine and see if it solves the problem:
[image]

Comment: That option is deprecated and should not be used, it doesn't "solve" anything it just fixes the symptoms. It's meant for buying some time for fixing broken scripts upon upgrading from earlier versions

Comment: Good idea but didn't fix my issue. This is a field update that fires on Opportunity Stage Change. If the field is null then the value is set and immediately reset to null. If there's a value the value is updated as expected.

Comment: @Alex I know that, but Turbo Forms still have some issues and that's the approach that MS Support suggested me a few months ago when the OnChange event of a field was being fired three times when programmatically (!!!) changing that field value. This is just a workaround for some specif cases (no scripting errors) and it's good that this is not the case :).